# std::out_of_range thrown when parsing a text file

Tags: c++, text, file-io

I have the following code to read a text file.

```
const string FILENAME = PACKAGES_DIR + pname;
  //the arguments to ifstream is a cstring and hence the conversion must be made
  ifstream freader;
  freader.open(FILENAME.c_str(),ios::in);
  if(freader.is_open())
  {
    while(freader.good())
    {
      string line;
      getline(freader,line);
      cout<<line<<endl;
      if(line.find("PackageId:"))
      {
        cout<<line.substr(11)<<endl;
      }
      else if(line.find("Name:"))
      {
        cout<<line.substr(5)<<endl;
      }
      else if(line.find("Version:"))
      {
        cout<<line.find(8)<<endl;
      }
      else
      {
        cout<<line<<endl;
      }

    }
  }
```

The contents of the text file in question is

```
PackageId:994
Name:basket
Version:1.80-1
Deps:kdebase-runtime,libc0.1,libc0.1-udeb,libc6,libc6-udeb,libc6.1,libc6.1-udeb,libgcc1,libgpg-error0,libgpgme11,libkdecore5,libkdeui5,libkfile4,libkio5,libkparts4,libkutils4,libphonon4,libqimageblitz4,libqt4-dbus,libqt4-network,libqt4-qt3support,libqt4-svg,libqt4-xml,libqtcore4,libqtgui4,libstdc++6,libunwind7,libx11-6,phonon
```

The output that I get is

```
PackageId:994
geId:994
Name:basket

Version:1.80-1
0-1
Deps:kdebase-runtime,libc0.1,libc0.1-udeb,libc6,libc6-udeb,libc6.1,libc6.1-udeb,libgcc1,libgpg-error0,libgpgme11,libkdecore5,libkdeui5,libkfile4,libkio5,libkparts4,libkutils4,libphonon4,libqimageblitz4,libqt4-dbus,libqt4-network,libqt4-qt3support,libqt4-svg,libqt4-xml,libqtcore4,libqtgui4,libstdc++6,libunwind7,libx11-6,phonon
e-runtime,libc0.1,libc0.1-udeb,libc6,libc6-udeb,libc6.1,libc6.1-udeb,libgcc1,libgpg-error0,libgpgme11,libkdecore5,libkdeui5,libkfile4,libkio5,libkparts4,libkutils4,libphonon4,libqimageblitz4,libqt4-dbus,libqt4-network,libqt4-qt3support,libqt4-svg,libqt4-xml,libqtcore4,libqtgui4,libstdc++6,libunwind7,libx11-6,phonon

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
```

The output that I wanted is:

```
PackageId:994
994
Name:basket
basket
Version:1.80-1
1.80-1
...
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: This can be simplified by using `while (getline(freader, line))` which also has a side effect of properly handling end of file.

Comment: @Thomas: ... which makes it more than a mere simplification! It changes the semantics of the OP's program considerably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem 1

`while .good` or `while !.eof` is *almost always wrong*. Throw away whatever book told you to do that, and [do this instead](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5).

In this case, the changed code looks a bit like this:

```
const string FILENAME = PACKAGES_DIR + pname;
//the arguments to ifstream is a cstring and hence the conversion must be made
ifstream freader(FILENAME.c_str(), ios::in);
if (freader) {
   string line;
   while (getline(freader,line)) {  // <-----
      cout << line << endl;

      if (line.find("PackageId:"))
         cout << line.substr(11) << endl;
      else if (line.find("Name:"))
         cout << line.substr(5) << endl;
      else if (line.find("Version:"))
         cout << line.find(8) << endl;
      else
         cout << line << endl;
   }
}
```

---

#### Problem 2

You're not using `std::string::find` correctly.

`line.find("PackageId:")` returns either "the position of the first occurrence in the string of the searched content", or the member value `npos` if the match is not found.

This combined with not performing bounds checks on the first parameter to `std::string::substr` is causing issues with your strings.

Instead, write:

```
if (line.find("PackageId:") != std::string::npos)
```

---

#### Problem 3

`cout<<line.find(8)<<endl;` should say `substr`, not `find`.

---

Your code with some of the above fixed:

```
const string FILENAME = PACKAGES_DIR + pname;
//the arguments to ifstream is a cstring and hence the conversion must be made
ifstream freader(FILENAME.c_str(), ios::in);
if (freader) {
   string line;
   while (getline(freader,line)) {  // <-----
      cout << line << endl;

      if (line.find("PackageId:")    != std::string::npos && line.size() > 11)
         cout << line.substr(11) << endl;
      else if (line.find("Name:")    != std::string::npos && line.size() > 5)
         cout << line.substr(5) << endl;
      else if (line.find("Version:") != std::string::npos && line.size() > 8)
         cout << line.substr(8) << endl;
      else
         cout << line << endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the exception thrown, it clearly tells you what is wrong.
The `what()` of the exception thrown prints out:

> what():  basic_string::substr

That tells you,
Exception is thrown by `substr`

See the documentation of **[string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)**:

> `string substr ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos ) const;`
>
> **Generate substring**
>
> Returns a string object with its contents initialized to a substring
>   of the current object.
>
> This substring is the character sequence that starts at character
>   position pos and has a length of n characters.
>
> *Parameters*
>
> - **pos**     Position of a character in the current string object to be used as starting character for the substring. **If the position passed is past the end of the string, an out_of_range exception is thrown.**
> - **n**     Length of the substring.   If this value would make the substring to span past the end of the current string content, only
>     those characters until the end of the string are used.     npos is a
>     static member constant value with the greatest possible value for an
>     element of type size_t, therefore, when this value is used, all the
>     characters between pos and the end of the string are used as the
>     initialization substring.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this.
It's not exactly clear to me.

Comment: What is my error?
if only one int is passed to substr then it returns the substr from that index to the end of the string.

Comment: I fixed the formatting to show where you have quoted the reference material; this should make your text a lot less confusing. And, really, rephrasing the exception text is not a particularly helpful answer, is it?

Comment: @nikhil: and if the string is `"PackageId:"`, then 11 is past the end of the string.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I've constructed the files in such a way that it won't be the case.

Comment: @nikhil: Your program isn't guaranteed that. And, frankly, neither are we.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I do not endorse spoon feeding homework.Eventhough the formatting may not be as good as it could be, Do you really think it didn't point out the error? Well I think it did,If OP wouldn't even want to read the API documentation after being pointed to it,then I feel to quote more than that is not spoon but actually force feeding.And we may not share the same views on this,so lets learn to live with it.

Comment: @Als: To be honest, in this specific instance, I think you've come too far away from the spoon! You're not even loading the food onto the spoon, or telling the OP what the food is, or what it's made of. Or _where_ he spilt it on the floor. You're just saying "you have the problem that you just told us about". Notice how the overarching problem with his loop has _nothing to do with `std::string::substr`_ whatsoever (even though, yes, it does make auxiliary bugs in his usage of that function apparent), so your answer doesn't point him helpfully to the correct area of study.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I posted the answer with the one problem I could spot and It is indeed a problem.As I already said, We may and certainly do not share the same views on many things including this,So learn to live with it.

Comment: @Als: OK, well, congratulations on spotting that his program was terminated by an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
      else if(line.find("Version:"))
      {
        cout<<line.find(8)<<endl; //<--------------------
      }
```

To

```
      else if(line.find("Version:"))
      {
        cout<<line.substr(8)<<endl; //<----------------------
      }
```

Comment: Wrong answer, as `std::string::npos` is usually always `true`. Though part of it is correct, you should have left out the `else if` line to at least not make it a wrong answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Was your comment in response to my answer?

Comment: @ChristianRau: `std::string::npos` is _never_ `true`. It's not even a boolean. (It is "truthy" though)

Comment: @ChristianRau, I was only referencing the `cout` line. The others were grabbed and pasted so the OP could visually reference the area referred to. The changed line was what I was suggesting change to. As the other answers here show, there is, of course, much more that needs to be addressed. I zeroed in on one problem.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Yes, of course. Nit-picky as always ;) But no problem I actually like that (honestly)!

Comment: @JonathanM: OK, but do make clear in that case which lines you have changed; that way, you're saying that you don't take responsibility for any of the others that you're just repeating.

Comment: @ChristianRau, easy on the mandates, friend. We're all here to help.

Comment: @JonathanM: Christian is merely suggesting a way to _better_ help the OP, and I agree with him! No need to get defensive. (And, FWIW, speak for yourself but don't speak for me, thanks: I'm not here to help at all!)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, no defense, just a suggestion to word things as friends. It's cool. (BTW, we appreciate your non-help. :) )

Comment: @JonathanM If this was in response to my comment on Tomalak's comment. This wans't meant with bad intention, as my last sentence should have shown (which wasn't meant sarcastic, honestly). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem that sticks out is that you try to read a line and use that line without checking if the read is successful.  Instead of checking if the file is good in the while condition, you should change your loop to something like this:

```
string line;
while(getline(freader,line))
{
    // now you can safely process line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using fixed constants for the `substr` positions, use a position variable:

```
std::string::size_t  position = 0;
static const char packageIdFieldName[] = "PackageId:";
position = find(packageIdFieldName);
if (position != std::string::npos)
{
    // The "sizeof('\0')" is a blantant reminder to subract
    //    the size of the terminating nul character.
    cout << line.substr(position + sizeof(packageIdFieldName) - sizeof('\0'))
         << endl;
    continue;
}
```